# sed swap any string with prefix from columns

Tags: string, awk, sed, swap

Hi people i tried search and look for any hints and not found it how to achieve to swap any matched string with prefix A_ in multiple columns to put into 4th column 
[enter image description here][1]

what guided me is below, but after many tries with regexes i stucked

> sed 's/(unix) (linux)/\2 \1/' textfile
>   linux unix os
>   windows mac os

Thank you

FROM

```
7      VAL  Z_SPLITIATO       A_DDDEW       84_SLA  841_SLON1   840_H1_S  
4      VAL  Z_SPLS_H5_C       SPIT_OAI      HD_CLA  A_AFASD
4      VAL  Z_SPLS_H6_C       SPIT_OAI      HD_CLA              A_ADFEEE
4      VAL  Z_SPLS_H7_C       HDS_H7OAISVC  A_SSEEWR
7      VAL  Z_SPLITIATO       SPL_N4_P1     A_EEEA  84SLOSA     IOOWWW  840_H1_SL
```

TO:

```
7      VAL  Z_SPLITIATO       A_DDDEW       84_SLA    841_SLON1   840_H1_S  IOOWWW
4      VAL  Z_SPLS_H5_C       A_AFASD       SPIT_OAI  HD_CLA
4      VAL  Z_SPLS_H6_C       A_ADFEEE      SPIT_OAI  A_ADFEEE
4      VAL  Z_SPLS_H7_C       A_SSEEWR      HDS_H7OAIS 
7      VAL  Z_SPLITIATO       A_EEEA        SPL_N4_P1  84SLOSA     IOOWWW  840_H1_SL

Value / Word with "A_" is placed randomly in multiple columns , number of columns is 20 so i placed here just few of them
```

Comment: added similar text , edited post

Comment: Please use `{}` button when you EDIT the post you will see it, use that  button to wrap up your input and output samples.

Comment: re-edited to have it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$  awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) 
           if($i~/^A_/) 
             {t=$i;$i=$4;$4=t; break}}1' file | 
   column -t
```

will give

```
7  VAL  Z_SPLITIATO  A_DDDEW   84_SLA        841_SLON1  840_H1_S
4  VAL  Z_SPLS_H5_C  A_AFASD   HD_CLA        SPIT_OAI
4  VAL  Z_SPLS_H6_C  A_ADFEEE  HD_CLA        SPIT_OAI
4  VAL  Z_SPLS_H7_C  A_SSEEWR  HDS_H7OAISVC
7  VAL  Z_SPLITIATO  A_EEEA    SPL_N4_P1     84SLOSA    IOOWWW    840_H1_SL
```

I think your 3rd row is not right, or perhaps I didn't understand the swap rule.

Comment: hi i will give a try now on dataset, thank you @karakfa

Comment: so swaping rule is not dependand on number 4 on 1st column it should be re-organized independently on that column

Comment: there is no dependence of 1st column.  Please check your output 3rd row for correctness.

Comment: true you are right, it works like a charm, thats great, thank you, ove you a beer